# High quality typesetting system

Tags: java, tex, typesetting

I'm looking for a high quality typesetting system to replace TeX.

My problem with TeX is that it's too brittle to deploy for John Doe. I need something that I can package with my Java app, unzip somewhere on the user's computer and be sure that it will work.

If the system is written in Java, that would be great but I'm collecting options right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching, I found these resources:

New Typesetting System (NTS): "The New Typesetting System (NTS) is a reimplementation of the typesetting system TeX in Java". Unfortunately, the project is dead and the website is down. From the Wikipedia article:

> First of all, NTS is too slow to be used for production purposes, which does not motivate users to switch to this engine. Furthermore, the by-then standard extensions such as e-TeX were not included in the code. Also, in order to be useful today, PDF output as well as pdfTeX-specific extensions need to be implemented. Finally, by being 100%-compatible with TeX, the sub-processes of NTS are rather interwoven (due to the nature of traditional TeX), which thereby makes the task of adding extensions less simple than had been envisaged.

The [ExTeX project](http://www.extex.org/index.html) took over. It's basically a reimplementation of TeX in Java and tries to improve TeX instead of creating a 1:1 clone in Java.

That means you get the layout engine plus a TeX parser but you can use either **or** both as you need.

Lastly, there is the [luaTeX project](http://www.luatex.org/) but it's a 1:1 clone, so it suffers from most of the shortcomings as TeX. Unlike ExTeX, they try to improve the situation in small steps, for example by allowing to write macros in [lua](http://www.lua.org/).

Comment: ExTeX seems to have died in 2009

Comment: @StephanEggermont: It's not completely dead; the single developer is still working on it but you can only see that when you check out the SVN repo. The build server is dead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very fond of the python documentation suite [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/). Deployed it in several organization with various level of computer knowledge and the result has always been great! Can generate html as well as LaTeX output.

Sphinx uses [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) as as its markup language.

Other candidates might be:

1. Perhaps simplified docbook docbook.org/schemas/simplified, but as you say, it doesen't define a render
2. [www.pango.org](http://www.pango.org/) and/or [pangopdf.sourceforge.net](http://pangopdf.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Uses (La-)TeX for high quality output.

Comment: missed the fact that LaTeX was a big nono for you. The only alternative I know of then is Docbook but it's not really lightweight... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook Perhaps simplified docbook http://www.docbook.org/schemas/simplified

Comment: docbook is only a markup language; it doesn't define a renderer. The standard only includes an XSLT transformation so the result is probably HTML - which is not a high quality typesetting language :-)

Comment: ok, last try: pango http://www.pango.org/Introduction and/or http://pangopdf.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

[Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) is very nice.

> If you need to convert files from one
>   markup format into another, pandoc is
>   your swiss-army knife. Need to
>   generate a man page from a markdown
>   file? No problem. LaTeX to Docbook?
>   Sure. HTML to MediaWiki? Yes, that
>   too. Pandoc can read markdown and
>   (subsets of) reStructuredText,
>   textile, HTML, and LaTeX, and it can
>   write plain text, markdown,
>   reStructuredText, HTML, LaTeX,
>   ConTeXt, PDF, RTF, DocBook XML,
>   OpenDocument XML, ODT, GNU Texinfo,
>   MediaWiki markup, textile, groff man
>   pages, Emacs org-mode, EPUB ebooks,
>   and S5 and Slidy HTML slide shows. PDF
>   output (via LaTeX) is also supported
>   with the included markdown2pdf wrapper
>   script.

Comment: What bothers me is "PDF output (via *LaTeX*)". I wanted to get rid of (La-)TeX :-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla Pandoc hides LaTeX from the user for basic use; isn't that enough? Afaik there is only one high quality typesetting system that is free, open and usable: LaTeX and friends.

Comment: @Raphael: No. I have Chinese characters and TrueType fonts in my documents and I spend 1-2 days during every upgrade of TeTeX to make my documents compile again.

Comment: @AaronDigulla I see. You might want to use XeLaTex or ConTeXt; I heard they deal better in such settings. (You meant TexLive, right?) It won't solve your "unzip and build" problem, but I don't think that *can* be solved at this time.

Comment: Another problem of TeX descendants is that they don't produce useful error messages (you need to be a human to parse them). I need something that I can integrate in my product.